# Solaris JumpStart JET server

Tags: solaris, jumpstart

I have configured the Jump Start installation on Solaris-10u9 which is running fine except one problem. i.e the registration page that is been included in new releases and I am unable to avoid it because of the solaris bug. But I have heard that Solaris Jump Start with JET package can be used to make it fully unattended installation. But I am bit confused about it,

Does JumpStart install server also needs to configure for JET to work or is it the Separte tool which does not have any dependency on jumpstart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JET works over the top of a jumpstart boot/install server. It is a readily available framework that allows you to use as is or build upon. The only requirement is that you have the solaris media available for the architecture you want to install.

Provided you have supplied all the information required by your jumpstart template, then by all means you should be able to achieve unattended installs.

Answer (score 0):

JET server is kind of advanced jumpstart installation method. I was unable to make it work 100% but Now i can configure the JET server. For this you need to install the SUNWjet package then configure the server.

For detailed info please follow the below links:
http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/archives/4734-Less-Known-Solaris-features-Jumpstart-Enterprise-Toolkit.html

Thanks & Regards
Ramesh Kumar